# How to select within a distance using QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, select-by-location

With QGIS 2.12.3, I have two projected EPSG:2927 point shapefiles, A and B.  I would like to create a selection of A points that are within 100 meters of any B point.

This is easy in Arc, using the Select by Location tool with the search distance option.

I am aware of two Select by Location tools in QGIS (Vector -> Research Tools -> Select by Location and the Spatial Query plugin).  However, neither has a search distance option.

In summary, how to do a QGIS Select by Location with a search distance?

Comment: Use the distance matrix tool

Comment: [Relevant post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179661/how-to-build-a-query-expression-to-select-specific-points-within-a-buffer-in-q)

Comment: This is an old post but having the same question I looked for the prior answers.  I didn't find anything near as easy as the ArcGIS Select by Location tool using the within a distance option or a search distance.    My workaround isn't too bad given how easy it is to create and remove temporary/in memory layers; I use the buffer tool to create a new polygon and then use that for the select by location.  But it still would be better to have the "buffer" built into the tool's options.