# Assigning attribute based on selection points on a graph?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I have a bunch of points on a map on a river that branches. I want an easy way to select one branch from the other and was hoping I could just somehow "grab" those points on the map and add a column to the attribute table with those points that would delineate the two branches.

Comment: Have you tried `'Select by location'`? For instance, there is a related thread [How to build a query/expression to select specific points within a buffer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179661/how-to-build-a-query-expression-to-select-specific-points-within-a-buffer-in-q). Or maybe this article can help you as well [Performing Spatial Queries](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_queries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Frist of all make an attribute to every single branch; every single branch of the river must be a single polygon's layer feature.

by your question I think you need to do the following steps:

**Step 1**
Generate a buffer poligon of every branch 
Qgis~Menù -> Vector -> Geoprocessing Tool -> Buffer. Set "distance" value in a way that you are sure to cover the points around every branch.

**Step 2**
Use the new buffered polygon layer in a spatial join of the points to add specific attribute
Qgis~Menù -> Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join attribute by location

Set "Input Layer = *yourPointsLayer* " and set "Join layer = *buffered-branch-layer* ", use these (check on) geometric predicate: "intersect, touch, are within", select the field to add (for example the field generated on step 1).

NOTE:
There are two important settings that are critical in the process

- The buffer size (step 1) must be not too small or too big
- The "join type" setting in spatial join (step 2)