# Concatenate and sequentially order unique groups of lines using SQL

Tags: qgis, sql, mapinfo

I have a segmented line (road) dataset that potentially runs through multiple area polygons (localities). I want the road dataset that is grouped by the unique field (RoadMntnc) to have a concatenated list of the localities it passes through in the direction of flow of the road.

The following partially works

```
select RoadMntnc, lower(Locality) from clip_DSC_Roads group by RoadMntnc, lower(Locality) order by RoadMntnc
```

But it lists every locality each segment is in and doesn't follow the direction of travel of the road.

[image]

I need the result as

```
Miallo_Bamboo_Creek_Rd | Miallo to Whyanbeel to Bamboo
Kingston_Rd | Whyanbeel
```

So if it is multiple localities (pink below) it should be in the direction that the road is.

To clarify a bit -there is a field with locality that changes in the dataset when a segment of road is inside different localities. It doesn't come from an external dataset -however if it has to then this won't be a problem either. This is why there is no 'intersect' in the SQL.

A QGIS or Mapinfo sql process would be fine as well.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Based on [Concatenate or group by values using spatial join in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179476/concatenate-or-group-by-values-using-spatial-join-in-qgis)

If I import the data into Spatialite and run

```
select RoadMntnc, group_concat(Locality) from clip_DSC_Roads group by RoadMntnc
```

I get
[image]

But how do get just the unique values and also check if it's in the right order?

I have tried

```
select RoadMntnc, distinct group_concat(Locality) from clip_DSC_Roads group by RoadMntnc
```

but get a syntax error.

Comment: If you are willing to use QGIS expressions, `aggregate()` and the `concatenate` function within it now have parameters to allow for extracting unique values and concatenating as of QGIS 3.8 (see this link: http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.8/#add-order-by-support-expression-aggregate-concaten) I would recommend standardising the type case of your input field before concatenating too so as to filter out duplicates more easily.

Comment: Thanks -that's how I got the list in the first place but the problem is it generates the list that I am now trying to clean up and show just the uniques. !--Concatenate( "Locality", group_by="RoadMntnc", concatenator=',')--!

Comment: @GeorgeC Did you try using `distinct`inside the group_concat expression?

Comment: @NettaB thanks. That works but the main issue still remains - it needs to be in the direction of flow of the road and not just random. !-- select RoadMntnc, group_concat(distinct lower(Locality)), count(RoadMntnc) as Count from clip_DSC_Roads_SL group by RoadMntnc --!

Comment: @GeorgeC add an 'order by' clause

Comment: @NettaB - yes it will order alphabetically but the requirement is to order it in direction of flow as per the OP.

Comment: @GeorgeC can't help you with order by, without the table definition and columns.

Comment: @NettaB - a sample of the data is in https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RL7VZL_giZuZ9xVfDFgk409_RIErIB0m?usp=sharing . In the question see the section with a screen grab under "I need the result as..." for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the answers in the comments:
1. In order to concatenate unique values with group by clause: `group_concat(distinct Locality)`

Order by:
2. Data ordering (by the data sample link from comment): From your data, it looks like that the start/End chainage fields are connected with the direction & order so this looks the most promising sql (see image):

`select RoadMntnc,  group_concat(distinct lower(Locality)) 
from clip_DSC_Roads 
group by RoadMntnc
order by RoadMntnc, Start_Chainage`

[image]

Comment: Works well since I had the start_chainage field. If anyone needs the full process - I had to run Dissolve by RoadMntnc first, then 'Points along geometry' (at 10m in my case). Finally on the segmented road dataset (not the dissolved one) I ran the following in field calc to get the start chainage for each Road segment - aggregate(layer:='DSC_Roads_10m_Chainage.tab', aggregate:='max', expression:="distance" * (attribute(@parent, 'RoadMntnc') = attribute($currentfeature, 'RoadMntnc')),filter:= within(start_point(geometry(@parent)),buffer($geometry,1,10)))